# rosjava compilation error when use rosmake

Tags: ros, rosmake, dependencies, rosjava, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi developers,

I have a problem when I try to execute the compilation of the sourcode from rosjava package.

It has not correct reference for libraries from ***org.ros.message.std_msg & org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs***

> ```
>   [javac] /rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/new_style/MessageImpl.java:409:
>   [javac] cannot find symbol  : class Char
>   [javac] location: class org.ros.internal.message.new_style.MessageImpl
>   [javac]   public List<Char> getCharList(String name) {
>   [javac]               ^
>   [javac]
> ```

/media/DATA/ros/rosjava/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/new_style/PrimitiveFieldType.java:24:

> ```
>   [javac] package org.ros.message.std_msgs does not exist
>   [javac] import org.ros.message.std_msgs.Char;
>   [javac]                                ^
>   [javac]  ....
> ```

Somebody knows what's the problem (and how to fix it)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10806/rosjava-compilation-error-when-use-rosmake/) by [enkulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/925/enkulator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

resolved, the problem was to update from older rosjava checkout to the new rosjava_core. The script **build-msg.xml** check if the folder of the messages are avaliable on the ros_home path (which is different that the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ) and if exists, not generate the new .jar files again.

The older jars have others format names, ex: roscpp.jar -> org.ros.rosjava.roscpp-0.0.0.jar

well finally I can do that my java projects can be connected with ROS ¡¡ fantastic ¡¡¡

---

Originally posted by [enkulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/925/enkulator/) with karma: 16 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0